# Create centroids from point layer based on unique field names

Tags: qgis, filter, centroids, qgis-3, feature-filter

I have a point layer in QGIS, which I want to filter by attribute values of a specific attribute column. For each unique attribute value, a centroid should be calculated from the respective features. This results in one centroid for each set of features containing a unique attribute value.

Example:
In the attribute column 'names', I have 10 features named 'aaa', 20 features named 'bbb', and so on. Now I want to create a centroid of the respective 10 'aaa' features, another centroid of the respective 20 'bbb' features, etc.

Anyone has some hints on how to do this?

Comment: To be sure of your problem, do you want create centroids of the features grouped by attribute?

Comment: Yes, grouped by attribute is another good description. The answer below exactly did what I needed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look at the `mean coordinates` tool. This should do exactly what you need.

[image]

Hand the tool a layer, maybe add a weighting value, and (this is important for you) tell the tool, which column contains your group IDs.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!